# How do I get the average string length in mysql?

Tags: sql, mysql

This:

```
SELECT AVG(LENGTH(string)) 
  FROM BLAH 
 LIMIT 10;
```

...seems to grind through all results. If I take off the AVG, it's way faster. Is it best to create a subquery like

```
SELECT AVG(len) 
  FROM (SELECT LENGTH(string) as len 
          FROM BLAH 
         LIMIT 10) as herp
```

This also seems slow. I don't want to load it all into php loop through with strlen. I was hoping there was a memory efficient solution.

Comment: Can you show us how you actually limit to an author's last X posts, and can you tell us why you hate subqueries?

Comment: I want to take an average of the first 2 entries in the list [1,2,3,4]. A subquery takes subset [1,2] then uses the avg() on it. It's better to add to an accumulator then divide, than have an arbitrary length set load into memory. As others have pointed out it's just an order by id desc, but really that part is not so significant.

Comment: the arbitrary length set is your problem *not* the `avg`. Think about how to limit your query to just the posts you are interested in without looking at them all (index on id etc, order by with limit, etc) *then* take an average of just those. Using `avg`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the first query loops through all the rows in the table (the limit 10 doest limit anything, since there will always be only 1 row returned)

the second query avg's rows 1 to 10

what kind of average are you looking for?

Comment: Getting the average post length in a writers forum for the last X entries they've made. I hate using subqueries so was hoping there was a better way.

Comment: @ForeverConfused nop there isn't, you can use a order by DESC in the subquery for the last 10

Comment: It's an average so technically it could just add to a counter and then divide by the number of entries it hit. The subquery way I show it goes through the items twice.

Comment: @Forever if you hate subqueries you need to work on getting over that - they are: essential, simple, readable and used everywhere by everyone. In short, get over it, you might as well hate the `select` keyword

Comment: @Forever likewise `avg`: there is no better or more efficient way of getting an average in SQL. Use it!